# use jquery ajax don't have callback when return true

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I try use query ajax and when I have "return false" I get callback as well

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#Form").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            success: function(callback){ 
                alert(callback);            
            } //success
        }); //ajax

        return false;

    }); //submit
}); //ready
```

in the php file I just echo "dennis", it works and I get alert with content "dennis".
when I try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#Form").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            success: function(callback){ 
                alert(callback);            
            } //success
        }); //ajax

    if (callback == "dennis"){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }   

    }); //submit
}); //ready
```

I get empty alert and the form act like he get "return true".
I also try put variable and return him, but still same problem..

why it happened? how fix it?

Comment: you can't access the `callback` var outside the anonymous success function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

Comment: You will have to put the

 if (callback == "dennis"){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }   

condition inside success function.

Comment: @RavinderSingh this will return from a different function

Comment: I mean to say that whatever output he gets from the ajax function will not be available outside ajax function.

Comment: your submit function will always return true.. that's how javascript works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the ajax-scope will execute asynchronous, hence when you check `if (callback == "dennis")`, you ajax call *may* not even reached your php yet, therefore callback will be *undefined*.

You need to check `callback` (it's actually a bad variable name as it is not a callback, but a *result* from your ajax-call) in the success scope.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST", 
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    success: function(callback){ 
       alert(callback);
       if (callback == 'dennis') {
           return true;
       } else return false;
    } //success
}); //ajax
```

Now, your next problem is that your form probably already returns true, so better calling a new function with your result, than returning true|false here.

```
 // ajax metod success function
    success: function(result){ 
       alert(callback);
       onFormReturn(result);
    } //success
```

and define the function to handle result

```
// elsewhere, outside ajax-scope - even outside document.ready
function onFormReturn(result) {
   if (result == "dennis") {
      // do your stuff
   } else {
      // do something else
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my first comment on your question, thats why its not working.

You *could* do something like this, but i **don't** recommend it:

```
var foo = null;

$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        foo = result;
    }
});

// use foo
```