# jQuery.ajax function doesn't return parameter from it

Tags: jquery

I need my function to return FALSE if user exists and TRUE if user doesn't exist in database. 
Here is my function code. Firebug showed me that variable flag stays undefined all the time. How can I fix it ?

```
function checkLogin(login, n) { 
        var flag;

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/checkLogin.ajax",
            data: "login="+login.val(), 

            success: function(response){
                if (response.status == "EMPTY") {
                    alert('Login is free - you can take it');
                    flag = true;
                } 

                if (response.status == "EXISTS") {              
                    alert('Login already exists in Database');
                    login.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    updateTips( n );
                    flag = false;
                }

            }
        });

        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Where's the amazing canonical duplicate for this question that appears way too often? I want to bookmark it

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155607/use-jquery-ajax-dont-have-callback-when-return-true/15156942#15156942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot return flag.. 
It will executed directly without considering your ajax call hence until your ajax call is in process, it will return the flag before ajax operation is done.
it will not work

You can take help of $.deferred instead

**[look at it](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)**

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous. Your return statement will occur before the callback code to alter the flag is completed. You need to change your logic so that the function doesn't return a flag, but rather passes it to a callback that you define.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

- `ajax` will work asynchronously, so you can't be sure it will complete (and therefore set flag) before you return the value you're waiting for it to set;
- and, you don't specify a handler for the `error` parameter, so if something is going wrong then you won't know about it.

Answer (score -1):

Try posting data as `data: "login:"+login.val(),`

use : instead of =

and also try posting data with '" + + "'

Comment: `name=value` is the proper syntax for a POST parameter.